# Change position of the path shown inside a file field

Tags: javascript, html

I have used a file field for uploading image in my site.When I browse and select an image the path of the image is shown in the field.But in IE this path moved down and so the path is not readable.What should I do to fix this issue ?

Comment: Which version of IE? Have you applied any styling to the file field?

Comment: I found this issue in IE 9.The style I have applied is -- 

font:14px/15px 'Arial', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#545454; width:248px; height:22px; border:thin solid #bbbbbb; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius:5px; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; background:#fff;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ramblex for your time.Any way I have found a solution for it.I have modified the style and this worked for me.

font:14px/20px 'Arial', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#545454; width:248px; height:22px; border:thin solid #bbbbbb; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius:5px; padding:0px 10px 0px 0px; background:#fff;

This is the code which worked for me.